# PHP can't get POST date value

Tags: php, mysql

I used PHP/MYSQL to create simple data management system,
here is my program fragment:

Search_index.html

```
<form action="Search_Date.php" method="post">
<p>
<label> Search Date : </label>
<input type = "text" name = "search_date">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Search">
</p>
</form>
```

Search_Date.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "dbConfig.php";


$min_length = 1;
$Create_Date = $_POST["search_date"];

function Search_POD_Create_Date($Create_Date)
{
    if(strlen($Create_Date) >= $min_length)
    {`enter code here`
        $POD_serial_no = htmlspecialchars($POD_serial_no); 
        $POD_serial_no = mysql_real_escape_string($POD_serial_no);
        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM model_info WHERE (`time` =          
        '$Create_Date') ");
        return $raw_results;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

function Show_Search_Table($raw_results)
{
    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
    { // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
        {
            echo "<p><h3>".$results['id']." ". $results['team']."   
                 ".$results['user']." ".$results['time']."<br>" ;
            echo "POD_model_no : <br>";
            echo "<h3>".$results['pod_serial_number'];
        }

    }
    else
    { // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }
}

?>

<?php
Show_Search_Table(Search_POD_Create_Date($Create_Date));
?>
```

And then when I click Search button, it shows "no result",
is there any problem I need to fix?
Please help me, Thank you!

Comment: try isset, if (isset($_POST["search_date"])) { $Create_Date = $_POST["search_date"]; } else {echo "no search_date";}

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Using `htmlspecialchars` on your input data is usually a big mistake. Don't do that, it just mangles things.

Comment: I have checked with your source and I got the value in `$_POST["search_date"]`. I think, problem must be in your functions. Debugging at each step will help you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to ensure that the `$_POST` is fetched the post data or not. so you have write and dump something like that `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` after start the `session_start();` function.

### And than check:

```
if(isset($_POST['search_date']))
{
   echo $_POST['search_date'];
}
else{
   echo "Not fetch value from HTML input field";
}
```

If you get the same data that you input on html input field and than try your function:

```
function Search_POD_Create_Date($Create_Date){
  // statements
}
```